# How to publish a vector< pair <int, int> >?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created a vector of type pair < int, int >, and now I'm trying to publish it on a ROS topic. The size of the vector is already known. How can I proceed ?

I have tried:

```
    vector_pub = nh.advertise<std::vector<pair <int, int> > >("vector", 100);
    vector_pub.publish(vector_node_position);
```

but it doesn't compile. Could you please help me?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269908/how-to-publish-a-vector%3C-pair-%3Cint,-int%3E-%3E?/) by [rosargh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31591/rosargh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way would be to create two custom messages, call them something like `my_msgs/Pair.msg` and `my_msgs/VectorPair.msg`. The contents would be:

**`my_msgs/Pair.msg`**

```
int a
int b
```

**`my_msgs/VectorPair.msg`**

```
my_msgs/Pair[] data
```

In your publishing node you would do:

```
#include <my_msgs/VectorPair.h>
vector_pub = nh.advertise<my_msgs::VectorPair>("vector", 100);
my_msgs Pair pair;
my_msgs::VectorPair vector_node_position;
pair.a = 1;
pair.b = 2;
vector_node_position.data.push_back(pair);
vector_pub.publish(vector_node_position);
```

Note that creating/populating the pair message and then pushing it into the vector message could happen inside a loop.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-30**:
And if you'd like to avoid having to create the msg at the `Publisher` side, see [ros/wiki/roscpp/MessageTraits](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesTraits). The `Subscriber` will still need the msg defs though.

**Comment by [rosargh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31591/rosargh/) on 2017-08-31**:
Thank you Thomas D and gvdhoorn, I'll try this right away and come back for a feedback :)